# What is the meaning 本心じゃない and ~言ってきた?

Tags: grammar

I'm unsure of what "本心じゃない" should represent and how to properly negate "本心" in the sentences below.
When I searched for the meaning of "本心", I found the following meaning:

-real intention
-one's right mind
-conformity to one's own sense of right conduct
-really mean
-true feelings

Did the word "intention" properly conveyed the meaning of the sentences below?

> **本心じゃなくて**カップルイメ—ジに合わせちゃっただけなのに。
>   It wasn’t intentional. But we still ended up becoming like a couples.
>   私が**本心じゃない**ってわかっててあんなこと**言ってきた**んだ。
>   When I understood that it was unintentional, I was saying such a thing.

I'm also unsure regarding how to interpret "~てきた". I tried searching for "てきた" explanation and I found this.
If the speaker at present says 「～てきた」, s/he is talking about something which started sometime in the past and continued until now or it can be "until sometime in the past".
So, I interpreted "あんなこと言ってきたんだ" as "I was saying such a thing".
But somehow the meaning of the whole sentence seems off.
Is my interpretation of the meaning of "あんなこと言ってきたんだ" wrong or just the interpretation of the sentence as a whole?

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but the context is a little unclear.  Are the two sentences uttered in that order by the same person?  Also, what was the statement like that is being referred to as あんなこと?   The more information you provide, the quicker a good answer will come.

Comment: The first sentence was said by the girlfriend.

Comment: The girlfriend's friend is telling her that her relationship w/ her boyfriend will get boring, if they always do the same things together. The sentence was said after the boyfriend heard (w/out her knowing) her agreeing to her friends that it's not good that she and her boyfriend is always going home together. So to get back at her. When she and her boyfriend met after class, he suggested that they should not go home together for a while because it's not good for their relationship. Here, the girl realized that he had heard her agreeing to her friends. She was walking home alone at this time.

Comment: The second sentence was again said by the girlfriend. It was said after her boyfriend suddenly appeared before her while she was sadly walking home alone. And the boyfriend told her that he didn't mean what he suggested and said that it's  very normal for them to be together since they are in a relationship and that there's nothing wrong with it..

Comment: Sorry, although I always use the word said. The two sentences are just things that the girlfriend is saying to herself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

本心 means true feeling, as it says, and 本心じゃない means that what was said was not sincere. So, 本心じゃなくてカップルイメ—ジに合わせちゃっただけなのに means "I wasn't serious, but just obeyed to how she thought of us".

As for 言ってきた, when you express how someone speaks to someone else, if he speaks to the direction that goes away from you in your perspective, you use 言う. In contrast, when he speaks to the direction that approaches to you, you use 言ってくる. (note that these include psychological sense)

So, 私が本心じゃないってわかっててあんなこと言ってきたんだ means "Ah, so he told me that while knowing that I wasn't serious!".

Without detailed explanations in the comments, I couldn't answer.

Comment: Now it makes perfect sense. :) Thank you very much. ^^